How to add a link that contains parentheses in a YouTube video description?
For example, if I wanted to link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_(film) from my YouTube video's description, if I add that directly to my description text then what I get is a broken link to:
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_(film

missing the trailing parenthesis + the ) as plaintext in description, i.e.:
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_(film">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_(film</a>)

How to best avoid that?

I could find two possibilities.

ChatGPT et al. suggest you percent encode the open and close parentheses with %28 and %29 respectively e.g.:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_%28film%29

you get (ignoring the link length limit):
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_%28film%29">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_%28film%29</a>

Slight downsides:

the percents will show in the link, making it less readable. But in general it doesn't matter much since the visible part of links is cut down extremely short anyways and so is usually just clickable. Also the parenthesis at the end like these is likely not going to show up at all
the parentheses will show in the browser bar after the user clicks it


r/NewTubers suggests surrounding the link with parentheses:
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_(film))

you get:
(<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_(film)">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_(film)</a>)

Downside: shows the extra parentheses added as a bit of noise.
Update: the link renders nicely on YouTube with ( and ), and if the user clicks it parentheses also show nicely in the address bar


I'm not intelligent enough to understand if parentheses need to be URL escaped in general: Is it ok to have brackets or parenthesis in URL? :-)
